# slidify('index.Rmd') gives Error: is.list(val) is not TRUE

Tags: r, slidify

I copied and pasted the Rmd from section #6 on this page http://zevross.com/blog/2014/11/19/creating-elegant-html-presentations-that-feature-r-code/ into an index.Rmd file and tried to slidify it. Results in an error. Same happens with any other example code. Is there something wrong with my solidify install?

```
> slidify('index.Rmd')


processing file: index.Rmd
  |................................                                 |  50%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: num 5


output file: index.md

Error: is.list(val) is not TRUE
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently received the same error. Through trial and error, I realized that a line above the YAML front matter at the top of the slide was throwing the error (I must have accidentally added one). After deleting that line, the error stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you knit the Rmd at least once already?

I had this problem and fixed it by running 'Knit HTML' first in RStudio (I'm sure there is an equivalent R command to the GUI button in RStudio) and then I ran the code:

```
slidify('index.Rmd')
browseURL('index.html')
```

My index.Rmd file is empty, so our scenarios may be different.